# Way to let user search by GPS

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gps, geocoding, datastore

I am building an application on google app engine with python and I have a Location entity that has a GPS property.  This property is stored as a string (though I could change this if need be) and I want to let the user type in a location and have my program return all the sites within 5 points of latitude or longitude.

I have the following code which gives me the location in GPS that the user is searching for but I am not sure what I can do from there and how I can do a query for all the GPS locations within my bounds.

```
class Map(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        #do some stuff here
    def post(self):
        inputlocation = self.request.get("q")

        #this returns the GPS location that the user searched for
        g = geocoders.Google()
        place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(inputlocation)

        #I would like to be able to do something like this         
        bound = 5
        upper = GPSlocation + bound
        lower = GPSlocation - bound
        left = GPSlocation + bound
        right = GPSlocation - bound

locations = db.GqlQuery("select * from Location where GPSlocation.lat<:1 and where GPSlocation.lat>:2 and where GPSlocation.long <:3 and where GPSlocation.long >:4 order by created desc limit 20", upper, lower, left, right)

        self.render('map.html', locations=locations, centerlocation=GPSlocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

searching by `5 points` is pretty easy, since that's just a square area:

```
select ...
where (GPSlocation.lat BETWEEN (:1 - 5) AND (:2 + 5))
   and (GPSlocation.long BETWEEN (:3 - 5) AND (:4 + 5))
```

if you were targeting a circular boundary, then you'd be in for a bit more math.

note that your where condition in your own query is invalid and will cause a syntax error. WHERE syntax is

```
WHERE (condition) AND (condition) ...
```

not

```
WHERE (condition) AND WHERE (condition) ...
                      ^^^^^---syntax error
```

Comment: do you have any idea if that works with GQL or is that just with SQL querying?

Comment: hmm. good point. no idea, actually. though it'd be kinda dumb to produce a syntax that's so very close to sql and then have enough missing/different bits like that...

Comment: yeah I agree though they do have many little differences and your method doesn't quite work though I was hopeful.  I'm debugging now

Answer (score 0):

A problem with your current code is the boundary cases.  First you have the Prime Meridian where your longitude goes from 0 to 360.  Then you have the poles where the latitude doesn't go above 90 or below -90.  This one is probably less of a concern (since they are where no one lives), but you need to decide that on a case by case basis. The longitude and Prime Meridian will give you fits if you need locations near that.